How to fix fncychap changing appendix cref name to "chapter"?
In my LaTeX document I use both cleveref and fncychap packages. But fncychap breaks the correct crefname for appendices.
A minimal example:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{fncychap}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\label{chap:first}

Reference to the \cref{app:first}.

\appendix
\chapter{First appendix}
\label{app:first}

\end{document}

It displays "Reference to the chapter A." instead of "Reference to the appendix A."
Without \usepackage{fncychap} it works as expected.
How can I fix that?

welcome! have you tried loading cleveref last?

I feel stupid... that worked!

cleveref likes being last. it should even be loaded after hyperref, which also likes being last ;).

@cabohah - Fair enough. I've withdrawn my close vote (and upvoted your answer).

As already told in a comment by @cfr you should load cleveref last (even after hyperref if you use hyperref):
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fncychap}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\label{chap:first}

Reference to the \cref{app:first}.

\appendix
\chapter{First appendix}
\label{app:first}

\end{document}

An alternative solution would be to use zref-clever instead of cleveref. The command \zcref can be used similar to \cref:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{fncychap}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\label{chap:first}

Reference to the \zcref{app:first}.

\appendix
\chapter{First appendix}
\label{app:first}% or \zlabel{app:first} → section 6 of the zref-clever user manual

\end{document}


